# How do you share classes between test configurations using SBT

Tags: scala, sbt

I have followed the instructions on SBT's documentation for setting up test configurations. I have three test configurations Test, IntegrationTest, and AcceptanceTest. So my src directory looks like this:

- src/

  - acceptance/

    - scala/
  - it/

    - scala/
  - test/

    - scala/

My question is, how can I configure SBT to allow sharing of classes between these configurations? Example: I have a class in the "it" configuration for simplifying database setup and tear down. One of my acceptance tests in the "acceptance" configuration could make use of this class. How do I make that "it" class available to the test in "acceptance"

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A configuration can extend another configuration to use that configuration's dependencies and classes.  For example, the [custom test configuration](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Testing#custom-test-configuration) section shows this definition for the custom configuration:

```
lazy val FunTest = config("fun") extend(Test)
```

The `extend` part means that the compiled normal test sources will be on the classpath for `fun` sources.  In your case, declare the `acceptance` configuration to extend the `it` configuration:

```
lazy val AcceptanceTest = config("acceptance") extend(IntegrationTest)
```

Comment: Ahh... This is much simpler. Thank you!

Comment: but they will also be run as Tests and compiled, so you need to have identical classpath

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me. AcceptanceTest cannot find classes from  IntegrationTest. Has anything changed since?

Comment: [updated link to sbt docs on custom test configurations](https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Testing.html#Custom+test+configuration)

Answer (score 13):

In case you want to stick with predefined configurations instead of defining new ones, and since both `Test` and `IntegrationTest` extend `Runtime` (one would expect `IntegrationTest` to extend `Test`…), you could use the following:

```
dependencyClasspath in IntegrationTest := (dependencyClasspath in IntegrationTest).value ++ (exportedProducts in Test).value
```

This should put all the classes you define in `Test` on the `IntegrationTest` classpth.

##EDIT:

I was just became aware to amuch better solution thanks to @mjhoy:

```
lazy val DeepIntegrationTest = IntegrationTest.extend(Test)
```

Comment: One note about this. This solution didn't work for my VSCode/Metals integration (although sbt compiled it fine). I found a fix here: https://github.com/scalacenter/bloop/issues/1162#issuecomment-585227295

Comment: This is a lot better!
I've been using the "hacky" solution for quite some time now. Perhaps when I first came up with it, `ConfigurationExtra.extend` wasn't implemented? or maybe I just wasn't aware so far. Anyway, thanks @mjhoy!

Answer (score 2):

An approach is documented here: http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Testing#additional-test-configurations-with-shared-sources

Comment: last time when I posted an url without good example, It was minus'd remorselessly :)

Answer (score 1):

SBT uses the [Maven default directory layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).

It will recognize folders unders `src/test/scala` to compile along with `src/main/scala`.

So, if you move the other folders under `src/test/scala` SBT will compile them and you can share code between them.  e.g.:

```
└── scala
    ├── acceptance
    │   └── scala
    │       └── Acceptance.scala
    ├── it
    │   └── scala
    │       └── IT.scala
    └── Test.scala
```

Running `sbt test` will compile all three files in the directory. So, with this Acceptance refer to and can create a new IT class for example.

Comment: Is this the only way? I do like the separation provided by having different configurations. I have it structured this way so sbt test will run unit tests, sbt it:test will run integration tests, and sbt acceptance:test will run acceptances tests. No other way to get it classes on acceptances class path?

Comment: No, I don't think this is the only way. You would have to add the custom source paths and classpaths to the build. Adding `scalaSource in Test := file("src/acceptance/scala")`  and `scalaSource in Test := file("src/it/scala")`
in the `build.sbt` file will get these paths to be compiled when `test` is ran.

Comment: Brilliant! This does exactly what I want. Thank you.

Comment: Well this definitely put me down the right path. This is what ultimately did the trick for me:                 `unmanagedSourceDirectories in AcceptanceTest <++= baseDirectory { base =>
  Seq(
    base / "src/acceptance/scala",
    base / "src/it/scala.scala"
  )
}`

Comment: How is `AcceptanceTest` defined?

Comment: It is set up in Build.scala `.configs(AcceptanceTest)
      .settings(inConfig(AcceptanceTest)(Defaults.testSettings) : _*)
      .settings(libraryDependencies += scalatest)`