# Passing command line argument to sbt test

Tags: scala, testing, sbt, typesafe-config

In sbt run config can be passed easily, for example as:

```
sbt "run -Dlib.lib1.version=2.0.0"
```

But a similar thing fails when arguments are passed to sbt test. For example:

```
sbt "test -Dlib.lib1.version=2.0.0"
```

[Official document](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Testing.html) states that sbt test doesn't support command line argument: "The test task accepts no command line arguments and runs all tests". I want to run test with different version of a library, the version is kept as a variable in the reference.conf, and I want to override this variable during test without changing the reference.conf each time.

So, how can I pass the config using command line argument to sbt test ?

Answer (score 4):

The `testOnly` task does allow you to pass command line arguments, and they will be honoured.

e.g. `sbt "testOnly MyTest -- -oU"` allows me to pass the -oU flag through to the scalatest runner from the shell.

In theory this only allows you to pass extra arguments to specific tests. But there's another feature you can take advantage of to hack around this. [testOnly parses wildcards in the test name](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Testing.html#testOnly).

So you can use a * wildcard to match every test and still pass arguments

`sbt "testOnly * -- -oU"`

passes the arguments after the * through to the test runner, and runs every test

Comment: That didn't run any tests for me (in version 1.2.8), I needed to use `sbt "testOnly -- -oU"` without the wildcard.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you can avoid passing the library version through the config file, you should be able to tell the sbt that you want different version via `% "someConfig"`, like:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.4" % "test"
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.6" % "it"
```

Note that these must not conflict, you can't have `lib % "test, it"` and `lib % "test"` because you will get a conflict.

Comment: Hi @insan-e, actually my case is little more complicated and I can't put it in the build.sbt. I am calling, a python code from scala and now I want to be able to test it against both python3 and python2 and the config variable is the only option in this case.

Comment: Hm, well, since you can't have 2 versions of same library in same test package, you could create a [custom test config](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Testing.html#Custom+test+configuration) in sbt, like `testPython2` and `testPython3`. Also, you can [extend existing test](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13386412/how-do-you-share-classes-between-test-configurations-using-sbt) config and use it's classes in your config.

Comment: your solution works, thanks. I am not accepting it as an answer, since its a work around the problem and not a solution to the problem.