# How Can I Share Code Between Integration Tests and Unit Tests

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest

For my tests I have created an object which holds all my Arbitrary instances of case classes (ie my generators):

```scala
object Generators
    extends
    FooGen
  {


  def sample[A](implicit gen: Gen[A]): A =
    gen.sample.getOrElse(sys.error(s"Could not generate instance with $gen"))

  implicit def arb[A](implicit g: Gen[A]): Arbitrary[A] = Arbitrary(g)

}

trait FooGen { this: GenUtils =>

  implicit val fooGen: Gen[Foo] = gen[Foo]

}
```

This currently sits under my /test folder as I need it to generate arbitrary instances of my cases classes for my unit tests. But now I want to create some integration tests which will be under my /it folder. What is the best way to share this generator file in my /test folder with my tests in /it folder?

I will have lots of these generators for all my case classes so I don't want to duplicate the code so that is why I am asking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on [gilad hoch's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55890145/5205022) try

```
IntegrationTest / dependencyClasspath := 
  (IntegrationTest / dependencyClasspath).value ++ (Test / exportedProducts).value
```

for example your `build.sbt` might look like

```
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .configs(IntegrationTest)
  .settings(
    Defaults.itSettings,
    libraryDependencies += scalaTest % "it,test",
    IntegrationTest / dependencyClasspath :=
      (IntegrationTest / dependencyClasspath).value ++ (Test / exportedProducts).value
  )
```

and the directory structure

```
├── it
│   └── scala
│       └── example
│           └── GoodbyeSpec.scala
├── main
│   └── scala
│       └── example
│           └── Hello.scala
└── test
    └── scala
        └── example
            ├── FooGen.scala
            └── HelloSpec.scala
```

so now `FooGen.scala` is accessible from `GoodbyeSpec.scala`.

Another option is creating a [multi-project](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Multi-Project.html) build and factor out common test code into its own project, perhaps `test-common`, and then have the main project [depend](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Multi-Project.html#Classpath+dependencies) on it

```
lazy val core = (project in file("core"))
  .dependsOn(testCommon)
  .settings(
    // other settings
  )

lazy val testCommon = (project in file("testCommon"))
  .settings(
    // other settings
  )
```