# Using a common test utility file for projects built in SBT

Tags: scala, unit-testing, sbt, integration-testing

Given a project using a `build.sbt` file, I would like to have a common `TestUtils.scala` file which the integration and unit tests both rely upon.

I have my src folder at `src/scala` and my integration testing folder at `it/scala`. My unit testing folder is at `test/scala`, and contains the common `TestsUtils.scala` file.

Currently I am running my tests through ScalaTest in Intellij. When I run it this way Intellij is able to determine the dependency from the integration testing folder on the unit testing folder. I am attempting to switch over to using a `test`, `it:test` and `unit:test` set of SBT tasks. When I do so the integration testing folder fails to compile since it can't find the common `TestUtils.scala` file. If I copy the `TestUtils.scala` file over to my integration testing folder then it does compile but I don't want to have the same code in 2 locations.

Here are the approaches I see to resolve this:

1. Copy the file into both test folders (bad)
2. Move the file into the `src` folder (introduces `src` reliance on `scalatest` which I would prefer to avoid)
3. Find a way for the `integration` folder to use the file from the `test` folder (don't know how to do this)

Ideally I would like to use the third approach but don't know how to actually implement it. How do you get one folder to use another folder as a dependency in SBT? Is there a better approach I'm unaware of?

Comment: Try `IntegrationTest / dependencyClasspath := (IntegrationTest / dependencyClasspath).value ++ (Test / exportedProducts).value` based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/61772756/5205022

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based off of the comment above by Mario Galic I slightly modified it to work for my build.sbt file. I used the following code:

```
   dependencyClasspath in IntegrationTest := (dependencyClasspath in IntegrationTest).value
  ++ (exportedProducts in Test).value
```